# PHP array with Ajax and Jquery - How to create dropdown from the data?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is the first time i've used AJAX and PHP.  I've written a simple login page (below). As you can see, Ajax will send the username to getLocations.php on blur, which i coded with the help of this site and youtube (i'm leaving out the db connect bit, but it's there):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head><title>Fetch JSON array Data</title>
    <script src="http://10.28.1.90/DC_CRM_HOME2_USER_RIGHTS/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#username").blur(function() {
                var sendu = $("#username").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "getLocations.php",
                    data: "username="+sendu,
                    success: function(response){
                        $("#result").html(locations+string+jqXHR);

                        //populate select with response...but how?
                          var locations = response.name;
                          for (var i in locations)
                          {
                            var vertical = locations[0];

                            $('select').append("<option value=\""+vertical+"\">"+vertical+"</option>");
                          }
                    }

                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
  <body>

    <form method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
        <input type="username" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" value="" /><br><p>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br><p>
        <select name="foo" id="foo">
          <option></option> 
        </select><br><p>
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="Login"  />
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

getLocations.php:

```
$name     = $_REQUEST['username']; //from ajax request

$query  = "select LOCATION ";
$query .= "FROM dc_MASTER.DC_CNSLR_ACCESS dca ";
$query .= "JOIN dc.MEMBERS m ON dca.id = m.id ";
$query .= "AND m.EMAIL = '$name' ";

$Sresult = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    if( ! $Sresult) {
        die("Database query failed: $Sresult");
    }
    $result = array();

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($Sresult) )

      $list = array_push($result, array('name' => $row[0]));

      $c = json_encode(array("result" => $result));
      echo $c;

?>
```

At this point, my array is "loaded" and i'm able to see the response in firebug:

```
{"result":[{"name":"Chenal"},{"name":"Heights"}]}
```

However, i can't seem to get my select options populated. I feel like i'm making this harder than it should be (and i've been staring at it for quite a while).  Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Instead of giving back an array of objects, each of which just has a name property only anyway, you should return just an array of values straight away. That you can loop through with a simple `for` loop. // What’s definitively wrong in your code is that you are trying to access `response.name`, but your response object does not have such a property – it’s `response.result`, and only that is an array of objects.

Comment: Consider giving feedback on your question next time.

Comment: Cbroe...thanks for the comment. All of these responses have been very helpful.  You guys are great...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through the JSON returned by the PHP:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L7a68y26/

```
var response = {"result":[{"name":"Chenal"},{"name":"Heights"}]}
var r = response.result;

for (var i in r)
{            
    $('select').append("<option value=\""+r[i].name+"\">"+r[i].name+"</option>");
}
```

In context:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getLocations.php",
    data: "username="+sendu,
    // Added this so jQuery knows what kind of data is being returned
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(response){
        var r = response.result;
        for (var i in r)
        {            
            $('select').append("<option value=\""+r[i].name+"\">"+r[i].name+"</option>");
        }
    }    
});
```

Comment: Dev, thank you for the reply.  Sorry i couldn't respond back quickly...3 kids under 5 yrs old makes it tough.This makes total sense and works great.  I made a one modification to wipe out the values once a new name is entered.

Comment: No problem, thanks for coming back! It happens too often that guys disappear when they get an answer!

Answer (score 0):

1) You haven't told jquery that you're expecting a json response back, so it'll just treat it as plain text.

```
$.post( 
    dataType: 'json'   // <<--you need this
```

With that, jquery will automatically parse/decode the JSON into a native JS data structure

2) Then it's a simple matter of looping:

```
 success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, opt) {
            $('select').blahblah + opt.name + blahblah
        })
```

On the efficiency side of things, while it's sometimes a good idea to pass around data AS data, but if all you're going to be doing with the data is stuffing it into a form field, you might be better off just building the HTML on the server and passing that around directly.

Comment: Thanks Marc...i'll give this an up vote. Appreciate the help and thoughts on other options